# Alignment Issues with ckeditor?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

We are using ck editor to customize our print layout, but there are lot of issues we are facing while working with the CkEditor. Mainly we were unable to fix alignment issues.

I have the following code:

```
<div align="right" style="padding:15px 150px 0 0;">Alignment problem</div>
```

The above line is displays properly in the browser, but the ckeditor is removing the 'align' property from the div.

Could you please any body tell me what might be the wrong here? Please suggest the best html editor if you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align` is not a valid attribute for a div ([it has been deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html)) so CKEditor removes it

Try the following instead:

```
<div style="padding:15px 150px 0 0; float:right;">Alignment problem</div>
```

Comment: thank you Pete, Could you please tell me why ckeditor is adding some special characters(?) unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

`align="right"` Is not right. Try `style="float:left; padding:15px 150px 0 0;"` or `style="padding:15px 150px 0 0;display:inline-block"` depending on what kind of behaviour yo wan't exactly.
Where did you find this align attribute? :-?

...if what you want is to align the text inside the div `text-align:left;` inside your `style` (left, right, center, justify...)

Consider also that maybe you are not loading your stylesheets **inside** the editor iframe.